# Make my own custom timeline for a website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, timeline

I'm a designer, but I also  do some programming (javascript, html, css). I need to create a custom timeline for a website (Couldn't post a photo because of insufficient reputation on here, but here's a link to the design: http://postimg.org/image/5p92wkk8f/  Like you hover the mouse over a part of the timeline, and according to that the year changes)  But I have no idea where to begin. (I tried looking it up on the internet, but there's no timeline code examples and I don't wanna generate a timeline from other websites, I wanna make a custom one that would be exactly like this design). Would anyone be able to give me hints, say anything useful, tell me where to start? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Timeline JS](http://timeline.verite.co/) is may be exactly what you are looking for. As it's open source tool, you can modify it as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make many divisions, one for each part (year in this case) of the timeline. So there'll be about 20 divs that together make the whole white line.

CSS would be something like:

```
.timeline { /*"timeline" is a class name that I made up.*/
    background-color:#ffffff; /* This is white color, change it to the cream color of the timeline.*/
    height: 30px; /*estimation*/
    width: 30px; /*estimation*/
    position:absolute;
}


.timeline:hover {
    background-color:#000000; /* This is black color, change it to the brownish background color.*/
}
```

This is just a part of the CSS. You'll need to position each division with margins. With the CSS code done, you'll have the timeline change it's color for each div you hover on.

The harder part is actually changing the text, and for it we'll use javascript. In order to make the code not too long (and easier for me to write) I'm going to write it as if there were only 2 divisions in the timeline. Once you get what I do, you will be able to finish it off easily.

So first of all, add an id to the division in which the text is, "text" e.g. In html, add to the 2 timeline divisions the event onmouseover, then a function. The functions are numbered.

```
<div id="text">Here is some text</div>
<div class="timeline" onmouseover="changeText1()"></div>
<div class="timeline" onmouseover="changeText2()"></div>
```

Now we need to write the functions. We'll make a variable which will include the whole "text" id, then make 2 functions (one for each div) and make each function change the text according to the function's number.

```
var text_div=document.getElementById("text");
function changeText1()
{
    text_div.innerHTML="Some Text"; //"Some Text" should be the text to be written when the user hovers his mouse on the FIRST part of the timeline.
}
function changeText2()
{
    text_div.innerHTML="Some Text"; //"Some Text" should be the text to be written when the user hovers his mouse on the SECOND part of the timeline.
}
```

So let's review. The CSS makes the division change color when hovered on. Additionally, when a division of the timeline is hovered, it will trigger a function from the javascript code which will change the text, according to which division was hovered on.

Another thing you should notice: In the image you added, there isn't one paragraph only, for each paragraph a different CSS code. The javascript code I wrote will change the whole "text" division, making it's CSS be the affecting one for the whole text you entered in javascript ("Some Text" part). If you wish the CSS to stay different, you should:

1. make for each paragraph its own id (in html).
2. then make a new variable in javascript for each id.
3. and then add a new line to each function, which will change the inner HTML of the new paragraph separately.

If something is unclear, please ask.

Comment: This is actually incredibly helpful, thank you so much! I'll get to it, and if I have questions I'll make sure to come back to you. Thanks again! :)